# Is SpannableString.setSpan() 2nd parm 0-based?

Tags: java, android, spanned

My empirical experiment shows that if I `setSpan(o, start, end)` from start to end of a string, where `end` is `String.length() - 1`, the last character isn't covered.

When I changed `end` to exactly `String.length()`, the entire string is covered and... I don't even get an "out-of-bound" exception.

Unfortunately, there is nothing in the documentation regarding this particular issue.

Can you confirm my observation? (or prove me wrong?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`end` is exclusive. `0, 2`, for example, is everything from `0` inclusive to `2` exclusive which is `0` and `1`.

Comment: So, if I understand you correct, to cover a String whose length is exactly 4 characters, start=0 and end=4?

Answer (score 2):

Most "ending" indexes will be exclusive as a matter of practice. That is, the ending index is one beyond the index of the last whatever-it-is. If SpannableString is the one from the Android SDK, then no, the documentation doesn't say this for method `setSpan`, though it does for other methods such as `subSequence`.